# How to send CSRF token through a cookie in Laravel 4, instead through a hidden input field

Tags: php, cookies, laravel

I use Laravel as a REST API - communicating with a SPA over on another domain.

I need help in sending the CSRF token over to my app.

I cannot echo it inside a hidden field, since my SPA is on another domain.

Can I place the CSRF token inside a cookie?

How can I do it?

I could send it through a get request - but I'm not sure it's safe.

Note: to be clearer, I'm thinking of sending the token inside a cookie, on my very first Get request.

Thank you!

Comment: Guys, what are your takes... is it safer to send the token through a cookie than directly through the JSON response - in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the function `csrf_token()` to create your cookie.

```
$tok = Cookie::make('token', csrf_token(), 30);
return Response::make('tadaaam')->withCookie($tok);
```

Or use it like this to append to a view.

```
$view = View::make('home');
$tok = Cookie::make('token', csrf_token(), 30);
return Response::make($view)->withCookie($tok);
```

To validate you should add a new filter.

```
Route::filter('csrfcookie', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Cookie::get('token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Comment: Ty Manuel, it works. What's your input in sending the token back through JSON and not through a cookie? Regarding security... is is safer through a cookie?

Comment: You surely could, but why reinventing cookies with JSON? I see no obvious difference regarding security, just more work for you.

Comment: Watch out. Cookies are being encrypted by default in Laravel 4.1.